# Transforming puzzle written in pure javascript to javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Javascript**

Script:

```
function move(cellID, cell) {
    if (cellID==emptyCell) return;
    rest = cellID % 5;
    topPos = (cellID>5) ? cellID-5 : -1;
    bottomPos = (cellID<21) ? cellID+5 : -1;
    leftPos = (rest!=1) ? cellID-1 : -1;
    rightPos = (rest>0) ? cellID+1 : -1;
    if (emptyCell!=topPos && emptyCell!=bottomPos && emptyCell!=leftPos && emptyCell!=rightPos)
    return; 

    cell1 = document.getElementById(emptyCell);
    img1 = cell1.firstChild;
    img = cell.firstChild;
    cell.removeChild(cell.firstChild);
    cell1.removeChild(cell1.firstChild);

    cell.appendChild(img1);
    cell1.appendChild(img);
    emptyCell = cellID;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="1" onClick="move(1,this);"></td>
    <td id="2" onClick="move(2,this);"></td>
    <td id="3" onClick="move(3,this);"></td>
    <td id="4" onClick="move(4,this);"></td>
    <td id="5" onClick="move(5,this);"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="6" onClick="move(6,this);"></td>
     ....
</table>
```

**Javascript with JQuery**

Script:

```
 $('td').click(function() {
    move(this.attr('id'), this);

 });


function move(cellID, cell) {
    if (cellID==emptyCell) return;
    rest = cellID % 4;
    topPos = (cellID>5) ? cellID-4 : -1;
    bottomPos = (cellID<13) ? cellID+4 : -1;
    leftPos = (rest!=1) ? cellID-1 : -1;
    rightPos = (rest>0) ? cellID+1 : -1;
    if (emptyCell!=topPos && emptyCell!=bottomPos && emptyCell!=leftPos && emptyCell!=rightPos)
    return; 

    cell1 = document.getElementById(emptyCell);
    img1 = cell1.firstChild;
    img = cell.firstChild;
    cell.removeChild(cell.firstChild);
    cell1.removeChild(cell1.firstChild);

    cell.appendChild(img1);
    cell1.appendChild(img);
    emptyCell = cellID;


}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="1" ></td>
    <td id="2" ></td>
    <td id="3" ></td>
    <td id="4" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="5" ></td>
    ...
</table>
```

Ok so I am slowly trying to transform a puzzle game from javascript to javascript using the jquery library. I succeeded the loading part of the puzzle in both javascript and jquery, in which the pieces of the puzzle load on the screen, but now I cannot get the `move` function to work. The `move` function is the one that is supposed to move the pieces on a click event. The pure javascript part of the code works completely. However the jquery part does not.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Thanks.

Comment: you refer to cell.firstChild, however the cells do not have any child, hows that?

Comment: `function move(cellsID, cells)` - you're not using second param or `move(this.attr('id'), this);` - second param is expected to be DOM element but it is most likely jQuery object

Comment: Please learn to use `var` to declare local variables. And wrap the body of `if` in `{}` even if it's just one line.

Comment: @rupps each td receives an img tag as child upon puzzle loading. I didn't want to put the loading part here but I should have probably mentioned that :)

Comment: @codemon, definitely, as that's the key thing you are moving!

Comment: It might speed up the help if you tell us what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a million ways to do that with JQuery. One of them is the following:

```
function moveCells(cell1id, cell2id) {
    var cell1=$("#"+cell1id),                    // your first cell
        cell2=$("#"+cell2id),                    // your second cell
        cell1contents=cell1.html(),              // whatever's inside the 1st cell
        cell2contents=cell2.html();              // whatever's inside the 2nd cell

    cell2.html(cell1contents);                   // put in 2nd cell whatever was inside the 1st
    cell1.html(cell2contents);                   // put in 1st cell whatever was inside the 2nd
}
```

Comment: Very nice, clean and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a function that is undefined in your click handler. It should be:

```
 $('td').click(function() {
    move(parseInt($(this).attr('id')), this);

 });
```

Edit: Added the parseInt so it will pass a number instead of the string representation of it

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or give us somewhere to look at it? The code above should call `move(1, this);` the same way your existing click handlers would.

Comment: Apparently my move function was at fault. The `parseInt` did help me after I changed my whole function. +1 thanks.